How to Deploy a Kotlin Multiplatform WebAssembly Project on a Web Server?
After building the project using JetBrains' official Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard and selecting only the Web option, I tried to deploy it on the server but only encountered a white screen.
What I Did

Project Setup: Used the Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard, choosing the Web option.

Build Commands:



Ran ./gradlew wasmJsBrowserDevelopmentRun, and the site worked perfectly with the development server running on my browser
Ran ./gradlew wasmJsBrowserProductionWebpack to build the production bundle.


Directory Structure Post-Build:

  └── js
   ├── node_modules
   ├── package.json
   ├── packages
   ├── packages_imported
   └── yarn.lock

Problem
My Hosting Provider is strato.de . They provide me a SFTP access where I uploaded the whole build folder, I am then able to specifiy a "home directory"
The description of home directory is as follows:

In the event of an internal redirection, point your domain to a
directory within your web presence.
You can either enter a directory directly or click on a directory.
Please ensure that a startup file is present in the selected directory
(e.g., index.html, index.php).

If I upload a basic index.html with some basic text, everything works fine but the index.html of this basic build is showing only a white screen.
Question

How can I properly deploy this Kotlin Multiplatform project to a standard web hosting environment? It should start the webpack server like it does with the ./gradlew wasmJsBrowserDevelopmentRun command, but on my Server.


You can run:
./gradlew wasmJsBrowserDistribution

Then the deployable website files will be located at:
composeApp/build/dist/wasmJs/productionExecutable

The files include index.html and *.wasm (among others).
Instructions available at:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/wasm-get-started.html#generate-artifacts

I am doing same but getting error

Task :composeApp:wasmJsBrowserProductionWebpack
asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
composeApp.js (542 KiB)
2eaba8643e2ccdf352b4.wasm (7.91 MiB)

entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
main (542 KiB)
composeApp.js

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
